# play more than one video from one activity in android

Tags: android

How to play more than one video from one activity in my android application? I have the following code:

```
VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
String movieurl = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/content1/bio_brain.mp4";

mc = new MediaController(this);
vd.setMediaController(mc);

vd.setVideoPath(movieurl);
vd.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer can play one video at a time. It has an [OnCompletionListener callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) you can register to get notified when playback stops. Then you can play the second video.

Comment: ok thanks but i want to play more then one video in one activity simultaneously using if else loop